# Funny gap to right of main <html> element

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

Hi I'm using Foundation css, with tweaks, on http://centuryplace.co.uk/alpha/

For some reason there's a funny gap to the right of the  element. 
I'm not sure what the issue is and have been looking for the solution on and off for the past week. Any help would be wonderful.
All the best. I've explained as best I can!

Screenshot showing bug:
[image]

Comment: Please re-edit your post and include a [mcve], e.g. code snippet which reproduces your problem and also a screenshot maybe where you point out what gap are you talking about. (Personally, I see a black background from side to side and no gap on the right. Even that white arrow is sticking to the right side of my screen.)

Comment: fix your code errors https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fcenturyplace.co.uk%2Falpha%2F#cl297c23

Comment: You need to remember the "minimal" part of the required markup posting.

Comment: Hi all 3, this question has now been improved (removed the HTML code which wasn't relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is issue in paddingStepOne class

Remove all left and right margins and check once(all media queries)

```
.paddingStepOne {
   margin: xxrem auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes it was to do with the margin pushing the width of the elements overall, over 100% width. This is fixed now on http://centuryplace.co.uk/alpha/

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at this css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px)
main.scss:331
.paddingStepOne {
  margin: 2rem 3.5rem;
}
```

The `margin` your adding here is causing the element to stretch beyond `100%` on the **The plans** title.

In this situation, I add the following temporary CSS:

```
* {
  border:1px solid red !important;
}
```

This will let you see which elements are causing the `100%` width to be affected.

Comment: Thank you, Znaneswar above you just spotted the same issue. This is now fixed on the live link. If you 'inspect element' you can see I've commented out the 'margin' property and replaced it with 'padding'

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in your CSS. You can tweak this change and then you can remove that gap or bar.
[Image of the class in which you have to do some changes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlRG1.png)

In `.cell` class, you have to remove these options

```
-webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
```

I did these changes and your problem of space to the right of the `html` element was solved. I am posting images of your website after changes.

[Image after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpClk.png)

I hope this will help you. All the best.